# Is it possible to send raw SQL to an Azure cloud db from Android?

Tags: java, android, sql, azure, azure-sql-database

I'm trying to implement Microsoft Azure's db as my mobile app backend.  I'm having a hard time finding comprehensive documentation.  I do see that I can query a table this way:

```
 mToDoTable.where().year("due").eq(2013).and().startsWith("text", "PRI0")
```

What I'd like to do is twofold:

1. create complex joins on tables or
2. send a parameter to a View or stored procedure that implements the complex join on the server side.

But I can't figure out how to do either.

There's a `.parameter()` method, but no indication of how I can catch that on the server to do anything useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was looking in the wrong place. It *may* be possible to directly query the SQL database, but that involves bypassing a lot of security and isn't really what I wanted.

The answer I found was that after setting up the database (and views and stored procs) in the SQL databse section of Azure, go to the Mobile Services section and create new APIs that run javascript and can run any sql, including query parameters.

I found this link very helpful: http://tapanila.net/windows-azure-mobile-services-custom-api-for-existing-sql-database/